# What is the cost of running an RPC Server?

Tags: rpc

I am planning to set up my own RPC server to run liquidator bots. What is the specific cost in case I am the only user and doing around 10 requests/min continuously?

Comment: You need to provide some more info in order to get a reasonable answer. For example: do you own the hardware? Are you planning on running bear metal? Are you looking for a cloud provider? Do you need a fallback? How many RPC nodes in the cluster? Are you considering running a block producing validator? In addition to your traffic, the validator would process all solana transactions so network ingress is also a substantial cost; do you care about network fees?

Answer (score 2):

Recommended requirements are:

- CPU. 16 cores / 32 threads, or more.
- RAM. 256 GB, or more.
- Disk. Consider a larger ledger disk if longer transaction history is required. Accounts and ledger should not be stored on the same disk.

https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-reqs

As an example, AWS EC2 has an `x2gd.4xlarge` instance that meets these requirements and costs $1.336/hr (us-east region), or **$962/mo**. You get 100 GB egress free per month + $0.09 per GB after. Add in storage cost (not sure how much you'll need), but then you have a ballpark number. If you sign a contract for 1yr+ you can reduce 15%+ off the EC2 bill.

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/

With a rate of 10 req/min you can easily use a free tier on many different RPC providers.